# JS plugin / Ruby gem for document viewer - 1 page at a time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

We have a requirement for reading uploaded files (stored on S3) in browser which can be of pdf, doc, ppt, txt type.
The exact need is to have a reader which opens just 1 page at a time and has previous/next button for navigating pages.
There should not be a scroll option to view next page.

Is there any JS plugin / gem available which provides 1 page at a time view with the navigation button ?

We found couple of solutions like:

1. PDF.js (restricted to pdf files only)
2. Google Docs Viewer (no option to view 1 page at a time)
3. ViewerJs - This was the closest match with our requirement but we are facing some issue like:

   - difficult in configuration to view files from S3
   - last commit was in Aug-2017

Expectation is something like this but for single page per view

[image: Expectation is something like this but for single page per view]